# What happens when we use this.setState() in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I am confused about when the state actually changes when this.setState() is used in React. Here is my JSX:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      iterator: 0
    }
  },
  handleClick: function () {
    console.log(this.state.iterator);
    this.setState({
      iterator: this.state.iterator + 1
    })
    console.log(this.state.iterator)
  },
  render: function () {
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.state.iterator}</button>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World"/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

As you can see, I am logging the state of iterator before and after this.setState() is called. But both the times, it is logging the same number. After the first time I click the button, I was expecting to log 0 and 1 respectively but they both log 0 and 0. And on second click, they log 1 and 1. So when is the state actually getting changed and what exactly is happening here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Citing https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

> Think of `setState()` as a *request* rather than an immediate command to
>   update the component. For better perceived performance, React may
>   delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React
>   does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.
>
> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
>   batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
>   right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use
>   `componentDidUpdate` or a `setState` callback (`setState(updater,
>   callback)`)

The second (optional) parameter is a callback function that will be executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered:

```
this.setState({
    iterator: this.state.iterator+1
  }, function(){
    console.log(this.state.iterator) 
});
```